# JSON data processing in c++14 (Boost)

Tags: c++, json, boost, c++14

I am new in C++ (I use most of the time embeded c). I have something like this JSON data:

```
[10, 
"Session" ,
{"currentYear":"2048","accidents":10,"status":"Accepted"}]
```

I am trying to process this data:

```
boost::json::value testVal;
boost::json::error_code ec;
testVal = boost::json::parse(data, ec);
```

So I have multiple items in testVal and I need to get object from testVal to test something like this:

```
boost::json::object testObj = testVal.get_object();
if(testObj.at("currentYear") == "2048")
{
// Do Something
}
```

But I am unable to get instance of object, where are the data which I am looking for.

Any idea how to check (using boost::json) if the data in currentYear are 2048?

Thank you for help.

Comment: testVal wouldn't be an object, it's an array and the 3rd thing in the array is the object you're looking for

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you a lot, finally it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward would be

**[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/YK6qzT)**

```
for (auto& element : testVal.as_array()) {
    if (!element.is_object())
        continue;
    if (element.as_object()["currentYear"].as_string() == "2048") {
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Though I recommend using the conversion facilities in the library. (Will add sample later)

### `value_to`

The magic conversions turn out a little bit contrived since your input is... underspecified. I'm assuming you filter the objects from the array, and let's for fun do case and whitespace insensitive parsing of the `Accepted` value into some kind of enum:

**[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nPvq3K)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace json = boost::json;
using boost::adaptors::filtered;

struct Insurance {
    long   currentYear, accidents;
    enum class Status { Accepted, Rejected, Pending } status;

    friend Status tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Status>,
                                json::value const& v) {
        using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

        static const struct S : symbols<Status> {
            S() { this->add
                ("accepted", Status::Accepted)
                ("rejected", Status::Rejected)
                ("pending", Status::Pending);
            }
        } _sym;

        Status result;
        auto& str = v.as_string();

        if (not phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), no_case[_sym] >> eoi,
                             space, result))
            throw std::domain_error("Status");
        return result;
    }
    friend Insurance tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Insurance>,
                                json::value const& v) {
        auto& o = v.as_object();
        return {
            std::atol(o.at("currentYear").as_string().data()),
            o.at("accidents").as_int64(),
            Status{}
        };
    }
};

json::value make_array(auto&& range) {
    return json::array(range.begin(), range.end());
}

int main() {
    auto data = boost::json::parse(R"(
        [10, 
        "Session",
        {"currentYear":"2048","accidents":10,"status":"Accepted"},
        {"currentYear":"2049","accidents":11,"status":" rejected"},
        {"currentYear":"2050","accidents":12,"status":"Accepted"},
        {"currentYear":"2051","accidents":13,"status":"pendinG"},
        12,
        "Session"
    ]
    )").as_array();

    auto objects = make_array(data | filtered(std::mem_fn(&json::value::is_object)));

    auto vec = json::value_to<std::vector<Insurance>>(objects);

    for (Insurance const& obj : vec) {
        std::cout << "Year: " << obj.currentYear
                  << " Accidents:" << obj.accidents << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Year: 2048 Accidents:10
Year: 2049 Accidents:11
Year: 2050 Accidents:12
Year: 2051 Accidents:13
```

Comment: assuming you want to look for objects in any position, not just go to the 3rd position immediately

Comment: There's a lot of assumptions that OP didn't give info on.

Comment: As promised added an inspirational example with `value_to` customization point: **[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4arYdG)**

Comment: Updated the sample to show off bulk conversion better https://godbolt.org/z/nPvq3K

Comment: Thank you a lot sehe, now I have to push these concepts into my C brain :D

Comment: It is better if `filtered` gives ForwardIterator than if it only gives InputIterator, because then the array construction can perform one allocation of the correct size instead of possibly multiple allocate/copy/free cycles.

Comment: @VinnieFalco Lukcily that's already the case https://godbolt.org/z/dzjWeo9oT (see static assert)