# Class cannot serialize itself using boost::json

Tags: c++, boost, boost-json, tag-invoke

I wrote a tiny class which relies on boost::json to serialize itself.
It fails to compile since compiler sounds to fail finding tag_invoke() functions which implement json::value<=>myClass translation :

```
/usr/include/boost/json/value_from.hpp:87:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘value_from_impl(CSpicaFTConfig&, std::remove_reference<boost::json::storage_ptr&>::type)’
 return detail::value_from_impl(
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
     std::forward<T>(t), std::move(sp));
```

An implementation of those 2 functions is given:

```
CSpicaFTConfig CSpicaFTConfig::tag_invoke(value_to_tag<CSpicaFTConfig>, value const &jv);
void CSpicaFTConfig::tag_invoke(value_from_tag, value &jv, CSpicaFTConfig const &cfg);
```

But compiler seems to be unable to find them.

Any hints are welcome !
Thanks

Comment: Please include the minimal, self contained example. Because **obviously** the error is in there. We can just show the fixed code.

Comment: Did you remeber to the make the methods static friends? See this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66710533/85371

Comment: Thanks, yes, tag_invoke() functions should be implemented as free freind external functions.

Comment: The class-name qualification (`CSpicaFTConfig::`) implies that they're not _free_ functions. And that's not required/recommended anyways. Probably the best is to declare the static friend functions _inline_ (inside the class). Marking a function `friend` inline automatically makes it `static` anyways, so that it behaves as a free function logically, except (1) ADL will find the functions (2) their inline declarations express that they're part of the class interface.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes, you're right : see my own anwser to the ticket below.
I declared tag_invoke() functions as CSpicaFTConfig class friend in the CSpicaFTConfig header, but gave them an implementation outside the CSpicaFTConfig namespace.
It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the proper way to implement tag_invoke() functions is to define them as free functions, friends of the object class (here it is CSpicaFTConfig ) to serialize:

```
  // CSpicaFTConfig => boost::json::value
  friend void tag_invoke(value_from_tag, value &jv, CSpicaFTConfig const &cfg);
  // boost::json::value => CSpicaFTConfig
  friend CSpicaFTConfig tag_invoke(value_to_tag<CSpicaFTConfig>, value const &jv);
```

Thanks for your support.